# ¿cómo evitar repetir productos en un carrito laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo la siguiente clase Cart que es la de un carrito de compras en Laravel que es la siguiente:

```
  <?php

     namespace App\Services;

     use App\Models\Coupon;
     use App\Models\Course;
     use App\Helpers\Currency;
     use Illuminate\Support\Collection;

     /**
    * Class Cart
      * @package App\Classes
      */

   class Cart
   {

/**
 * @var Collection
 */
protected Collection $cart;

/**
 * Cart constructor.
 */
public function __construct()
{
    if (session()->has("cart")) {
        $this->cart = session("cart");
    } else {
        $this->cart = new Collection;
    }
}

/**
 *
 * Get cart contents
 *
 */
public function getContent(): Collection
{
    return $this->cart;
}

/**
 * Save the cart on session
 */
protected function save(): void
{
    session()->put("cart", $this->cart);
    session()->save();
}

/**
 *
 * Add course on cart
 *
 * @param Course $course
 */
public function addCourse(Course $course): void
{
        $this->cart->push($course);
        $this->save();
}


/**
 *
 * Remove course from cart
 *
 * @param int $id
 */
public function removeCourse(int $id): void
{
    $this->cart = $this->cart->reject(function (Course $course) use ($id) {
        return $course->id === $id;
    });
    $this->save();
}

/**
 *
 * calculates the total cost in the cart
 *
 * @param bool $formatted
 * @return mixed
 */
public function totalAmount($formatted = true)
{
    $amount = $this->cart->sum(function (Course $course) {
        return $course->price;
    });
    if ($formatted) {
        return Currency::formatCurrency($amount);
    }
    return $amount;
}

/**
 *
 * all taxes for cart
 *
 * @param bool $formatted
 * @return float|int|string
 */
public function taxes($formatted = true)
{
    $total = $this->totalAmount(false);
    if ($total) {
        $total = ($total * env('TAXES')) / 100;
        if ($formatted) {
            return Currency::formatCurrency($total);
        }
        return $total;
    }
    return 0;
}

/**
 *
 * Total products in cart
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function hasProducts(): int
{
    return $this->cart->count();
}

/*
 * Clear cart
 */
public function clear(): void
{
    $this->cart = new Collection;
    $this->save();
}

/**
 *
 * calculates the total cost in the cart with coupon
 *
 * @param bool $formatted
 * @return string
 */
public function totalAmountWithDiscount($formatted = true)
{
    $amount = $this->totalAmount(false);
    $withDiscount = $amount;
    if (session()->has("coupon")) {
        $coupon = Coupon::available(session("coupon"))->first();
        if (!$coupon) {
            return $amount;
        }

        $coursesInCart = $this->getContent()->pluck("id");
        if ($coursesInCart) {
            // courses attached to coupon in database
            $coursesForApply = $coupon->courses()->whereIn("id", $coursesInCart);

            // id courses attached on database for apply coupon
            $idCourses = $coursesForApply->pluck("id")->toArray();

            if (!count($idCourses)) {
                $this->removeCoupon();
                session()->flash("message", ["danger", __("El cupón no se puede aplicar")]);
                return $amount;
            }

            // total price courses without discount applied
            $priceCourses = $coursesForApply->sum("price");

            // check discount type and apply
            if ($coupon->discount_type === Coupon::PERCENT) {
                $discount = round($priceCourses - ($priceCourses * ((100 - $coupon->discount) / 100)), 2);
                $withDiscount = $amount - $discount;
            }
            if ($coupon->discount_type === Coupon::PRICE) {
                $withDiscount = $amount - $coupon->discount;
            }
        } else {
            $this->removeCoupon();
            return $amount;
        }
    }
    if ($formatted) {
        return Currency::formatCurrency($withDiscount);
    }
    return $withDiscount;
}

protected function removeCoupon(): void
{
    session()->remove("coupon");
    session()->save();
}
}
```

La clase cart me funciona desde la creación de carrito, agregar productos, aplicar los cupones, mostrar el precio y el total, aplicar el descuento del cupon, etc.

EL único detalle es el siguiente, al agregar un producto se puede volver a agregar el mismo producto como es la siguiente imagen:

[image: productos duplicados en un carrito]

Pude buscar sobre utilizar contains, pero la duda es dónde implementar si tengo que hacer un nuevo método dentro de mi clase Cart o tengo que implementar contains en el método addCourse, si me pudieran ayudar por favor.

Answer (score 0):

Si estas manejando algún tipo de **id** para el producto solo cuando agregues verifica sí ya existe en tu carrito con un **if()**, sí existe aumenta la cantidad ++ y si no manejas por cantidad solo manda una variable a la vista que diga que ya existe.

Comment: Ok entiendo pero enqué parte de mi clase haria eso y como sería?

Comment: Podrías poner el código dónde agregas el producto, así podremos ayudarte mejor

Comment: Aquí es donde se agrega cada producto

/**
 *
 * Add course on cart
 *
 * @param Course $course
 */
public function addCourse(Course $course): void
{
        $this->cart->push($course);
        $this->save();
}